# Not redirecting to my own view after login with Django and AllAuth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-allauth

I'm getting familiar with Django and I'm trying to use django-allauth and the issue I found is that I cannot redirect to my own view after login. Let me share a piece of code:

this is the form I have in the login.html template:

```
<form action="{% url 'webapp:home' %}" method="post" class="margin-bottom-0">
            {% csrf_token %}
   ...
 </form>
```

Here is my url.py defined inside my app:

```
app_name = 'webapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path(route='', view=views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

I also defined my namespace:

```
path("workspace/", include("picnic.webapp.url", namespace="webapp")),
```

Now, every time login succeeds, I got the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/workspace/ which matches with login and it's redirecting me to the login page again... How can I force allauth to send me to http://127.0.0.1:800/workspace instead the url is currently sending me?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

states that you have to set the:

`login_redirect_url` in your settings

and there is a issue with your login form, the action specifies the url the form posts to, the default from `allauth` is this:

`action="{% url 'account_login' %}"`

Check that you have the urls from allauth included in the base `urls.py`:

`url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),`

**EDIT:**

I guess
`picnic.webapp.url` should be `picnic.webapp.urls`?

Comment: bb4l, thanks for your answer my friend, but this was the first thing I tried and it doesn't work cause is redirecting me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/confirm-email/ even when I have  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL="home" in my settings

Comment: have you changed the loginview?

Comment: have you set `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS`  to `False`?

Comment: Here is the status of the project right now: I guess picnic.webapp.url should be picnic.webapp.urls? -> 1) Yes it is, there was a typo when I posted, but yes... it's correct in the project. 2) ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory" 3) ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False 4) LOGIN_URL = "account_login" 5) <form action="{% url 'account_login' %}" method="post" class="margin-bottom-0"> 6) path("workspace/", include("picnic.webapp.urls", namespace="webapp")),

Comment: This was the my first try and even thought with this config, after login, it's redirecting me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/confirm-email/, and I don't want to confirm anything, I want to move directly to home without creating a new view class to capture my confirm-email url and manuall. redirecting it to home. I don't want that. Again please, I'm new using django, I'm pretty sure that i'm doing something wrong

Comment: is the email verified? / confirmed?